# Is there a way to use Arquillian to test my project without MAVEN?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, ant, jboss-arquillian

I need help to find the answer how to use `Arquillian` without `Maven` to 
test my java project

Before some one asks why, I have to do it without `Maven` because I already implemented `ANT` technology in the project, and I don't want to do it in maven again.

I have an `EAR` project with a `WAR` and `JAR` project in it...if it matters

I need some sort of advice, because on the net I simply can not find any site that shows how to use `Arquillian` without `Maven`...

Can you help me?

Comment: There is a more detailed question at the following link.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42770056/using-arquillian-with-just-ant